# What is the right place to ask about "identifying this game/device?"

Tags: support, site-recommendation

For example, if someone didn't know what a tamagotchi was, they could ask:

Identify this game device:

1) had a digital pet

2) old, small device

3) can hand in keychain

4) japan item

Where would I ask these types of questions?

Comment: I'm not sure there is anywhere. Arqade is the gaming site but they don't allow game identification questions.

Comment: Most of our sites that did allow identification requests (which this certainly would fall under) have since decided to disallow them - they tend to be of very limited utility to the community and typically only the asker. We want to optimize questions (and answers) to maximum utility - so they are helpful to as many people as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with showing an image, and expecting people to identify it is *it is really hard* to find that question, and its horribly localized.

*Personally* I'd ask about such things in chat *knowing* the chat has people interested in such things.

QA is typically bad for this and quite a few sites discourage this. On SU for example, we've been trying to get rid of hardware ID questions by semi-rolling them into a [generic hardware ID question](https://superuser.com/questions/709913/how-do-i-identify-hardware-i-am-unfamiliar-with-on-my-computer).

This is also made a little more complex by a certain oddness of scope since there's no real site that those random electronic tchotchkes are on topic.